# Moving multiple sets columns into a single set of columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with columns of data in A-B-C-D-E for a single Person's Data.
Then, the same headers are repeated in columns F-G-H-i-J, for a 2nd Person's Data
Then, the same headers are repeated again in the next 5 columns, and this goes on for 25 sets of columns (so I have data for 25 people going across). 
There are about 50 rows down of this data.

The data headers are as follows:

> A-Name
>   B-DOB
>   C-Level
>   D-Acct#
>   E-Tshirt Size
>
> F-Name
>   G-DOB
>   H-Level
>   I-Acct#
>   E-Tshirt Size

Repeating for 25 sets

I would like to move all of the data so that is is in only columns A-B-C-D-E.
I would like ALL of the Names to appear in Column A, All of the DOBs to appear in Column B, etc.

I have seen something similar to this posted here but I don't understand how to re-write the code to fit my specific situation.

I have struggled with this problem for 3 years and copy/pasted everything by hand which takes hours.  I would really appreciated any information on how to automate this.

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the code you've tried and where you are stuck. This is very doable and we can help you better if you tell us where you are stuck in your coding process.

Comment: Record a macro of the manual copy and paste to start

Answer (score 0):

it needs fiddling with but here's a start:

```
Sub CopySomeCells()

    With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("myExample")

         lastcellincolumnA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.xlUp).Row
         lastcellincolumnL = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 12).End(Excel.xlUp).Row

        .Range("G1:L" & lastcellincolumnL).Copy
        .Range("A" & (lastcellincolumnA + 1)).PasteSpecial Excel.xlValues

    End With

End Sub
```